# How can I typecast my 2d slice of string to []byte?

Tags: go, casting

I have created a 2d slices and populated it from backend database but as json.Unmarshal accepts only []byte as first parameter **how can I typecast my 2d slice to []byte.**

Here is the sample code for reference as I can't share internal code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

//User sjd
type User struct {
    EmailList [][]string `json:"emailList"`
}

func listHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    var user User
    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &user)
    el := user.EmailList 
    keys := make([][]string, 0)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(el), &keys) //this line not working because []byte(el) not possible
    fmt.Println(keys)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(el))//this line not working because []byte(el) not possible
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", listHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Sample request:

```
{
    "emailList": [
        [
            "akki@gmail.com",
            "bakki@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "lakki@gmail.com",
            "jakki@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: You don't. You're unmarshaling _into_ your `keys`. The data you're unmarshaling should be a `[]byte`.

Comment: Thanks @JimB I am not unmarshaling into keys. I have to call something like `json.Unmarshal(keys, &user)`. Which requires keys to be of type `[]byte`

Comment: If you have a `[][]string`, that's not something you unmarshal, Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @JimB I have updated the question and indicated where I am stuck.

Comment: `keys` simply cannot be json, because it's a `[][]string`. Why is in `keys` that you think needs to be decoded? `Users.EmailList` is also a `[][]string`, what is the difference between that and `keys`? You need to include example data in your code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @JimB Updated question with sample request

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You've already decoded that json into `User`, and `user.EmailList` is already  a `[][]string` with the data you seem to want. There's nothing left here to decode. For example: https://play.golang.org/p/2TsmJTm5HhX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unmarshal` JSON as `[]byte` to `user`. `Marshal` `user.EmailList` to JSON as `[]byte`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type User struct {
    EmailList [][]string `json:"emailList"`
}

func main() {
    // rBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    rBody := []byte(`
{
    "emailList": [
        [
            "akki@gmail.com",
            "bakki@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "lakki@gmail.com",
            "jakki@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
}
    `)
    fmt.Println(string(rBody))

    var user User
    err := json.Unmarshal(rBody, &user)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(user.EmailList)

    wData, err := json.Marshal(user.EmailList) // wData is []byte
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(wData) // wData is []byte
    fmt.Println(string(wData))
    // _, err = w.Write(wData)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/S3HWiTqz--B

Output:

```
{
    "emailList": [
        [
            "akki@gmail.com",
            "bakki@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "lakki@gmail.com",
            "jakki@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
}

[[akki@gmail.com bakki@gmail.com] [lakki@gmail.com jakki@gmail.com]]
[91 91 34 97 107 107 105 64 103 109 97 105 108 46 99 111 109 34 44 34 98 97 107 107 105 64 103 109 97 105 108 46 99 111 109 34 93 44 91 34 108 97 107 107 105 64 103 109 97 105 108 46 99 111 109 34 44 34 106 97 107 107 105 64 103 109 97 105 108 46 99 111 109 34 93 93]
[["akki@gmail.com","bakki@gmail.com"],["lakki@gmail.com","jakki@gmail.com"]]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. The expected output was:
`[
        [
            "akki@gmail.com",
            "bakki@gmail.com"
        ],
        [
            "lakki@gmail.com",
            "jakki@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]`. Your answer helped me getting the desired result.